# Creating actor comprising multiple other actors - controlling where pieces are drawn

Tags: libgdx, transformation, scene2d

I am making my custom actor class, made up of 3 actors (one`ProgressBar`, one `Label` and one `TextButton`), because I will be using this many times, so it's not a good idea to create 3 of those actors separately when I can create one that can contain them. So I am making my class:

```
public class MyActor extends Actor {
ProgressBar bar;
Label nameLabel;
TextButton button;
public MyActor(String name, Skin skin, float progress){
    nameLabel = new Label(name, skin);
    button = new TextButton("Buy", skin);
    bar = new ProgressBar(0f,5f,progress,false,skin);
}


@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    bar.setBounds(getX(), getTop()-getHeight() / 3f, getWidth(), getHeight() / 3f);
    nameLabel.setBounds(getX(), getY()+getHeight() / 3f, getWidth(), getHeight() / 3f);
    button.setBounds(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight() / 3f);
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    bar.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    nameLabel.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    button.draw(batch,parentAlpha);
}


}
```

So in my game, I add my actor to the Stage using a table:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.debug();
MyActor actor = new MyActor("whatever",mySkin,1f);
table.add(actor).size(myWidth,myHeight);
```

The actor is drawn in the correct place (I know because of the debug lines), but the 3 actor are drawn at the 0,0 coordinates. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to override another method?

Answer (score 1):

**From the comments:** the solution seems to be to make `MyActor` extend `Group`, then add the constituent actors to that group.

---

**Original answer:**

It looks like your problem could be that your `MyActor` class does not report it's width and height to the parent `Actor`. Just because you have an `Actor` that has some other `Actor`s as members doesn't mean the "*parent*" `Actor` will know how tall and wide it should be to accommodate all of them.

By querying the preferred size of the child `Actor`s you can return more sensible values by overriding `getHeight` and `getWidth`;

```
public class MyActor extends Actor {
    Label nameLabel;
    TextButton button;
    ProgressBar bar;

    public MyActor(String name, Skin skin, float progress){
        nameLabel = new Label(name, skin);
        button = new TextButton("Buy", skin);
        bar = new ProgressBar(0f, 5f, progress, false, skin);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);

        button.setBounds(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), button.getPrefHeight());
        nameLabel.setBounds(getX(), button.getTop(), getWidth(), nameLabel.getPrefHeight());
        bar.setBounds(getX(), nameLabel.getTop(), getWidth(), nameLabel.getPrefHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public float getWidth() {
        return Math.max(bar.getPrefWidth(), Math.max(nameLabel.getPrefWidth(), button.getPrefWidth()));
    }

    @Override
    public float getHeight() {
        return nameLabel.getPrefHeight() + button.getPrefHeight() + bar.getPrefHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        nameLabel.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        bar.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        button.draw(batch,parentAlpha);
    }
}
```

I also changed the layout logic to consider the preferred size of the children, instead of saying that each should be a third of the whole in height, for example.

Also, if your `table` is the root table, I think you want to set it to fill the parent;

```
Table table = new Table();
table.setFillParent(true);
```

Comment: It still gets drawn in the left bottom corner of the screen, it's just longer. :/

Comment: @Asaltaviejas Is your `table` the root table? If this is the case is should probably fill its parent. I've added a part to the end of my answer about this.

Comment: I already solved it, instead of doing `MyActor` extends from `Actor` it extends from `Group` and I just added the 2 actor to the it. :D